# Plot values of a line from a grayscale image

Tags: c#, graph, graphics, photo

I am trying to take a grayscale bitmap and extract a single line from it and then graph the gray values. I got something to work, but I'm not really happy with it. It just seems slow and tedious. I am sure someone has a better idea

```
WriteableBitmap someImg; //camera image
int imgWidth = someImg.PixelWidth;
int imgHeight = someImg.PixelHeight;

Int32Rect rectLine = new Int32Rect(0, imgHeight / 2, imgWidth, 1); //horizontal line half way down the image as a rectangle with height 1
//calculate stride and buffer size
int imgStride = (imgWidth * someImg.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8; // not sure I understand this part
byte[] buffer = new byte[imgStride * rectLine.Height];
//copy pixels to buffer
someImg.CopyPixels(rectLine, buffer, imgStride, 0);
const int xGraphHeight = 256;
WriteableBitmap xgraph = new WriteableBitmap(imgWidth, xGraphHeight, someImg.DpiX, someImg.DpiY, PixelFormats.Gray8, null);
//loop through pixels
for (int i = 0; i < imgWidth; i++)
     {
        Int32Rect dot = new Int32Rect(i, buffer[i], 1, 1);  //1x1 rectangle
        byte[] WhiteDotByte = { 255 };                      //white
        xgraph.WritePixels(dot, WhiteDotByte, imgStride, 0);//write pixel 
     }
```

[image: the image and the graph below it]

You can see the image and the plot below the green line. I guess I am having some WPF issues that make it look funny but that's a problem for another post.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the goal is to create a plot of the pixel value intensities of the selected line.

The first approach to consider it to use an actual plotting library. I have used [oxyplot](https://oxyplot.github.io/), it works fine, but is lacking in some aspects. Unless you have specific performance requirements this will likely be the most flexible approach to take.

If you actually want to render to an image you might be better of using unsafe code to access the pixel values directly. For example:

```
xgraph.Lock(); 
for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++){
 var rowPtr = (byte*)(xgraph.BackBuffer + y * xgraph.BackBufferStride);
 for(int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++){
    rowPtr[x] = (byte)(y < buffer[i] ? 0 : 255);
  }
}
self.Unlock(); // this should be placed in a finally statement
```

This should be faster than writing 1x1 rectangles. It should also write columns instead of single pixels, and that should help making the graph more visible. You might also consider allowing arbitrary image height and scale the comparison value.

If you want to plot the pixel values along an arbitrary line, and not just a horizontal one. You can take equidistant samples along the line, and use [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) to sample the image.

Comment: I had a look at OxyPlot again. It seems to be based on PolyLines, which I was thinking of implementing myself. I'll see if it's fast enough for what I need...